# apt-get install php-db FreeBSD equivalent

Tags: php, pear, freebsd, freeradius

I am trying to get daloradius https://github.com/lirantal/daloradius to work in FreeBSD with php 5.6. When I try to login, I get this error:

Fatal error: Class 'DB' not found in /.../library/opendb.php on line 86

Tried the following but didn't work:

```
pkg install php-dba
pear install DB
pear install MDB2
```

Now on my linux box, I got this error initially but when I ran the following it worked:

```
apt-get install php-db
```

In FreeBSD this doesn't work. Can anyone tell me the equivalent of this to FreeBSD? Or has anyone been able to get daloRadius to work in FreeBSD? Thank you so much.

PS I also tried pointing the include code to the absolute location of the DB.php **(/usr/....../pear/DB.php)** and it didn't work.

Comment: when you tried these commands what was the error ?Have you tried to search for missing package ? `pkg search -f package_name`

Comment: no errors in FreeBSD but in daloradius, I get the same DB.php error. Yes I have tried doing pkg search but there are no matches when it comes to php-db

Answer (score 2):

If I am right DBA is not in the default `pkg php56-extensions` but what you can do is install from source and select the required extensions, for doing this do:

```
# portsnap fetch extract
```

Then:

```
# cd /usr/ports/lang/php56-extensions
# make config <--- select [x] DBA dba support
# make install
```

That will install the DBA extension, more info about using ports can be found here: https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/ports-using.html

Comment: hi nbari, apparently the FreeBSD flavor that comes with pfSense doesn't allow these commands to be run. I was trying and researching about them

Answer (score 1):

`lang/php56-extensions` is a meta-package that just pulls in other dependencies according to config. So, instead of installing all default extensions, you can install just `databases/php56-dba`.

And it is not necessary to compile it, `pkg install php56-dba` will also do.

Comment: thanks for the reply. but i tried pkg install php56-dba and i am still getting the error about the DB.php file not being found.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is the pear DB library. On FreeBSD the pear packages have a pear- prefix instead of php-

Try:

```
# pkg install pear-DB
```

Comment: hi Craig, thanks for the reply but I tried that and it still doesnt work.

Comment: _"Does not work"_ is meaningless without the actual error quoted. We are all mortals here and incapable of telepathy... Help us help you by quoting any diagnostics you get back from the commands suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct to use `pkg`. But you have to use the correct package-names. The name of the php-dba package on FreeBSD today depends on the PHP-version you'd like:

- `php56-dba`
- `php70-dba`
- `php71-dba`

For the pear packages you listed, the package-names are `pear-DB` and `pear-MDB2` respectively. Both are built using PHP-5.6 by default, however, so, if you want to use the versions *pre-built* for you, you'll need to use PHP-5.6 (and `php56-dba`).

But it seems, you've installed all of the relevant packages already -- and your problem is with a particular application (daloradus?). Thus, your question is neither about FreeBSD nor installing packages on same, and you should edit its title and tags to match.